# How to load SVG images in next.js using file-loader?

Tags: webpack, next.js

I have added the following loading configuration:

```js
config.module.rules.unshift({
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      esModule: false,
      name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
      outputPath: 'static/images',
    },
  },
});
```

This does generate the expected files:

```
❯ ls -l .next/static/images/*-*.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 gajus  staff  2755 Oct 11 19:05 .next/static/images/BAGEL-c8eb9c0fab3c81a8ce2ca37b91e45447.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 gajus  staff  1399 Oct 11 19:05 .next/static/images/CARROT-6f210c93ab8a1dffb7613368a5cbb5fe.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 gajus  staff  1223 Oct 11 19:05 .next/static/images/CHOCOLATE_BAR-26d9835f780bee61f42a772bcc4b0358.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 gajus  staff  1643 Oct 11 19:05 .next/static/images/COOKIE-dc51bfc82c7bec0bc39a79de154027d2.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 gajus  staff  1779 Oct 11 19:05 .next/static/images/CROISSANT-fbbd24736806af790ed7b7eff9c29ce5.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 gajus  staff  4255 Oct 11 19:05 .next/static/images/DOUGHNUT-9cd981749f95b790e0c14fdd24189117.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 gajus  staff  1275 Oct 11 19:05 .next/static/images/MANGO-6318f4f9015e40d8d2177b299afc7563.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 gajus  staff   639 Oct 11 19:05 .next/static/images/RED_APPLE-9ad3d18099978a24a614c5f58a8d198b.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 gajus  staff  1975 Oct 11 19:05 .next/static/images/SHORTCAKE-cb1521d4a45c8e4b808d6309fbc4690c.svg
```

However, the actual images contain base64 encoded content, e.g.

```
cat .next/static/images/BAGEL-c8eb9c0fab3c81a8ce2ca37b91e45447.svg | head -c 100
export default "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMzYgMzYiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3L
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what I was looking for, but I managed to simply disable `url-loader`.

```js
const imageRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) => {
  return String(rule.test) === String(/\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif)$/i);
});

if (!imageRule) {
  throw new Error('Unexpected state');
}

const fallback = imageRule.oneOf[imageRule.oneOf.length - 1];

if (fallback.resourceQuery) {
  throw new Error('Unexpected state');
}

const urlLoader = fallback.use[0];

if (urlLoader.loader !== 'url-loader') {
  throw new Error('Unexpected state');
}
```

The logic for disabling `url-loader` for images is that they are rarely part of critical user experience and technologies such as HTTP2 made it easy to load these resources in parallel.

I've raised an issue asking if there is a better way to do it https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/17804.